# Convert probabilities from logistic regression to classes

Tags: r, mgcv

I've fit a multinomial logistic regression using `gam()` and the `mgcv` package in R. I then used this model to make predictions on new data. The resulting predictions are probabilities because `gam()` doesn't have a `type="class"` option. I'd like to convert these probabilities to one of my three levels for my categorical response variable but I have two questions: 1) How should I determine where make the probability threshold between the three classes? and 2). How can I make a nested `ifelse()` statement that reclassifies the probabilities according to the thresholds?

Comment: what is the dimension  of your probabilities?. consider doing `max.col(probabilities)`

Comment: What do you mean? The probabilities range from 0-1 and I have one of those values in a dataframe for each of the 10,000 new data points I asked it to predict. Is that helpful?

Comment: surely you should be able to tell what dimension is. Lets say you get probabilities for the first point. You should have something like `0.1, 0.7, 0.2` etc. The reason you get three probabilities is because there are three classes. Hence your dimension is 10000 * 3.

Comment: The right way to go about determining classification thresholds is to compute the threshold from the benefit which you get for a correct classification and the loss which you get for mistaking one class for another. In a 2-class problem, that leads to a threshold on the posterior odds which is a simple function of the benefit and loss. In a 3-class problem, the result is still simple enough to calculate, although I don't know if it is so neat (I haven't worked it out myself, no doubt someone has it somewhere).

Comment: Ah! Yes, sorry. Dimensions are 10463 x 3. Doing max.col seemed to work reasonably well, although Robert's response sounds like there might a more sophisticated and accurate way to do it?

Comment: The term "accurate" is probably not appropriate. For 3 groups, assigning an observation to the group with .334 assigns the observation to the group to which it most likely belongs. But the benefit of getting it right versus the cost of getting it wrong may lead you to guess/predict more liberally or more conservatively. That depends entirely on your data and your research question(s) which we know nothing about. There is a difference between making a mistake when predicting your favorite ice cream versus predicting that you do not have a terminal disease when you do have one.